# Using OpenLayers example in OpenStreetMap Wiki?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openstreetmap, openlayers

I'm trying to work my way through **[this wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example)** to add OSM into a OpenLayers map I am working on, however I cannot even get the first example to work.

I have downloaded OpenLayers V3, copied the code into a text file (saved as html), then copied "os.js" into the same folder, not "openlayers.js" as it says in the example, this doesn't appear to exist so i think i copied the correct one. I'm also not sure what it means as the "theme directory" as well.

Anyone managed to get this to work, if so then how? And is there any other ways this could be done?

Comment: Which browser have you used to check html file? If Chrome, it can be problem with src file (it won't read files like that).

Comment: Tried it in both Chrome and IE and not got anywhere with it yet...

Comment: I'm quite sure that page uses OL2, not 3. They are not compatible.

Comment: Any idea what would change to make it work in OL3?

Comment: Simple openlayers 3 example http://jsfiddle.net/29bsw/1/ your source is for openlayers 2.

Comment: @Mapperz do you have an example of this being used as it would be in a html incl. the link to the .js library? Just so i can check it's not something else I have done incorrectly. Thanks

Comment: With a wiki (html link) http://jsfiddle.net/VictorVelarde/DbCgt/

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz, I am now looking at bringing this together with a WMS layer I had previously had a different .js library for that is brought through Geoserver. Where would I bring this layer in within the code you provided?

Comment: just add wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS http://jsfiddle.net/jSQrj/21/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21779/discussion-between-joshua-dickerson-and-mapperz).

Comment: chat blocked at work...

Comment: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/examples/ has lots of examples for using OpenStreetMap tiles or WMS.

Comment: Thanks @scai, had looked through them before, just hadn't realised that the Wiki page was in OL2. The only part I seem to be having issues with now is the .js library working with some tests i run but not others when i use OSM with geoserver?